# Merging/Cherry-Picking a range of Commits from Branch A to Branch B

Tags: git, gitlab, git-merge, git-bash, cherry-pick

I have the following git history:

```
...--A--B--C--D---E--I--M--N--O--P   <-- Branch-A
  \  \       /
   \  F--G--H
    \
     J--K--L   <-- Branch-B (HEAD)
```

I want to Merge/Cherry-Pick commits (I .. P) to the branch (Branch-B)

I have tried git cherry-pick using following command:

```bash
git cherry-pick I..P
```

But instead of merging from commit I to P. cherry-pick is being performed from I to A (i.e. backwards in the history).

Any Solutions? Solutions other than cherry-pick are also welcome.

Comment: Can you describe how you see that the applied commits are "I to A" ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Updated - I've been looking at this, and I can't see how the command you've specified would do what you're saying it did.  If you start with `Branch-B` checked out and say

```
git cherry-pick I..P
```

then you should get copies of the commits from `M` to `P` added to `Branch-B`.  Since you want to also get `I`, you should say `E..P` instead, but the idea of `cherry-pick` working "backwards" through the history doesn't make sense, or match the docs, or match my tests.

I've also adjusted my answer a bit.  I still prefer to use `rebase` for ranges of commits, but I originally said it's the "easiest" way, and objectively that's not accurate since it requires extra manipulation of branches.

---

The way I would duplicate the changes of a range of commits (so long as that range doesn't include merges) is with `git rebase` using the `--onto` option.  That might look like this:

```
git rebase --onto Branch-B E P
```

Note that you specify `E`, not `I`, as the "upstream" argument.  That's because rebase treats this argument as a negative ref - everything reachable from `E` (including `E` itself) will not be copied.

Also note that I specified `P` as the final argument, rather than `branch-A`.  That's because if you do a rebase with a branch checked out, the branch moves with the rewritten commits, and it doens't sound like you want that.  The result is that you're now in detached HEAD state, and the rewritten commits are not currently on any branch.

```
...--A--B--C--D---E--I--M--N--O--P   <-- Branch-A
  \  \       /
   \  F--G--H
    \
     J--K--L   <-- Branch-B 
            \
             I'--M'--N'--O'--P' <-- (HEAD)
```

To integrate these commits into `Branch-B` you could now

```
git branch -f Branch-B
git chekcout Branch-B
```

or

```
git checkout branch
git merge -
```

to get

```
...--A--B--C--D---E--I--M--N--O--P   <-- Branch-A
  \  \       /
   \  F--G--H
    \
     J--K--L--I'--M'--N'--O'--P' <-- Branch-B (HEAD)
```

Comment: Once I execute the command the cherry-pick merges the changes done in commit E. Finds conflict and ask me to resolve. After resolution and commiting the changes, I execute git cherry-pick --continue. And it asks me to edit comment for merge commit E, D... respectively.  I know thats not how it should behave. I'll try with git rebase --onto and will share update here. @Mark

Answer (score 0):

That makes no sense. If the first revision you would like to see applied on branchB is `I`, you need to try like rhis:

```
git cherry-pick E..P
```